# Upload a big dataset .geojson file on Mapbox using AWS services and Mapbox api

Tags: amazon-web-services, upload, dataset, mapbox

I want to upload big dataset file in .geojson on the map website Mapbox, but the size is limited at 5mb, so i need to upload it with the api : https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=JavaScript#uploads

But nothing works, i tried to do that with cURL ans the AWS CLI, but when I try to copy the file in the Amazon S3 bucket I have that :

```
upload failed: .\map.geojson to map.geojson An error occurred 
(InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: The 
AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I don't know how to do it, the documentation is very short and in JavaScript I don't know how to use the documentation with the code.

I am completely lost and this is important, somebody can help me ?

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: No, the dataset file was too large for Mapbox, I have tried to separate the file in tiny files accepted by Mapbox, and the service stop working after the upload of half data.

Comment: You can Use Dataset API to first use createDataset to create a dataset in mapbox and then use putFeature api to upload your features to that dataset using the api, this way you don't have to worry about the size.